# Calculate intermediary control points in Cubic Bezier Curves

Tags: bezier-curve

I need to programatically generate two-dimensional circles of various dimensions, knowing only their radius and position. The circles will be drawn by employing 4 cubic Bezier curves.
How should I calculate the Cartesian coordinates of the two intermediary control points of each arc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_B%C3%A9zier_curve#Approximating_circular_arcs) has it all worked out.

The control points between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are at $(1,k)$ and $(k,1)$ with $k=\frac43(\sqrt2-1)$.

Comment: Thank you, joriki. For some reason missed the article Bezier Splines. I can see it now linked at the bottom of the Bezier Curves article where this very matter is being discussed.

Comment: @ADwarf: You're welcome!

Comment: @joriki I've been working on this for three days, wrestling binomial coefficients, Bernstein Basis Polynomials and Catmull-Rom splines,  but for a programmer like me the math talk is just too dense. I know that k is something like 0.55. Now (1,k) and (k,1) appear to be coordinates in this answer, but they're actually closed intervals, right? So how do I calculate control points p1 and p2, given begin and end coordinates p0(50,50) and p3(250,50)?

Comment: @ElisevanLooij: No, they're coordinates. Your $p_0$ and $p_3$ don't define a unique arc; even if I assume that you want a quarter-circle, there are two different quarter-circles with those two endpoints. Find a linear transformation that maps the quarter-circle about the origin through $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to the quarter-circle you want, then apply that transformation to $(1,k)$ and $(k,1)$ to get the control points.